# Tk Get the window path currently in focus

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

How do i get the current window in focus using Tcl/Tk. 
I tried using the focus command but it returns and empty string.

I have mutiple windows in the same wish session. Each window has
the same set of buttons but different data. I need to find out the
path to the window from which the button was pressed.

Answer (score 4):

The `focus` command with no arguments returns the current Tk widget with the focus or an empty result if no Tk widget has focus. You can test this by starting Tk and packing some windows, then use `after 2000 {puts [focus]}` and click in a window within the 2 seconds.

However! What you want to achive sounds better done by binding the button command and passing itself to the command procedure:

```
pack [button .b -text Click -command [list Click .b]]
proc Click {widget args} {puts [list $widget $args [focus]]}
```

If you add an entry widget in there you will find the focus does not necessarily equal the button widget when you click it. That requires tabbing to the button first.

Comment: Thanks patthoyts. I tried using focus but it was returning an empty string. I guess I need to set the focus first for this to work. I will go ahead and use the second approach for now.

Comment: @balaji If the keyboard focus isn't _actively_ in a Tk widget, `[focus]` returns an empty string. This tends to matter in a debugging session where the focus has returned to your interactive terminal. :-)

Answer (score 0):

While looking for something else, I came across this, and while it's a bit old.. In Tcl, the there is a better way to do this. For 
one thing, you cannot be sure the "active window" is the window you want when the script runs. The way to know which window/button was pressed is to embed it in the script code. When you attach code to Tk window/widget with the "-command" parameter, you can use something like "[list mycommand uniqueid]", and the Tcl interpreter will append any documented arguments before executing it. An excellent example of this is making a TCP socket server in Tcl. The command is "socket -server <procname> <port>", where the <procname> gets called whenever a client tries to connect to the <port>. But it does not have to be a simple procname, it can be any Tcl command that can be eval'd: "socket -server [list myserver foo bar] 12344" will create a listening socket on port 12345. When a client tries to connect to the server, Tcl will call (technically, it'll run it through "eval") "myserver foo bar <chan> <addr> <port>", where chan, addr and port are parameters added to the command by the socket command. Those are documented in the Tcl socket command pages.

The important part here is to understand that Tcl calls "myserver" with the arguments you gave it then appends the additional arguments to the end. You can then listen on another socket with "socket -server myserver foo baz 12346", which would listen on port 12346, and when a client connects, it will call/eval "myserver foo baz <chan> <addr> <port>". You can then write a single "myserver" proc as "`proc myserver {argFoo argBar argChan argAddr argPort} {if {$argBar eq "bar"} {puts "do somthing"} else if {$argBar eq "baz"} {puts "do something else"} else {puts "Whatcha' talkin' about, foo'!?"}}`".

For a Tk button example:

```
button .pressme -text "Press Me!" -command [list cmdYouPressed [pid]]
proc cmdYouPressed {argPID args} {
  puts "You pressed the button for $argPID!"
}
```

If you run this snippet in multiple different Tcl/Tk interps, you can tell which one got pressed by the process ID (thats what the [pid] was for) to know which button got pressed in which running script. Of course, you can create your own unique identifiers instead of using [pid], as I did with the foo bar/baz socket example.

Doing it this way eliminates many problems that simply trying to get the active window has, such as "what happens if the window is NOT active when the command runs, such as if you have some kind of automation/remote control going and it's responding to a background window?" It also makes it so you do not have to try to determine the window/resource id when you have multiple version of the script running--each already has it's own system-unique process ID.

(Sorry if I'm not being clear or being too terse.. My keyboard is not working correctly, which is why I was searching for something else, to help me "autocorrect" the errors..)